# Toolbar Overlay in android

Tags: android, user-interface, toolbar

I am trying to come up with a view like [image] where the picture starts from behind the overlayed toolbar any ideas. Is it some sort of immersive mode or something else

Comment: Actually is over the toolbar and status bar.

Comment: please post the answer if any you found

Answer (score -1):

I'd follow this steps:

1. Use ScrimInsetLayout by Google. (I think is included in the Support Design Library, otherwise just copy paste from Google IO app source code).
2. Set the transparency of the inset as 100% transparent.
3. Here's the trick: I think the upper darker section in the photo above  is not a semitransparent layer on the status bar but a layer on the image itself. I think that because of the head of the guy appearing over the status bar completely. So make your images with that layer being whatever you want, you can even do a wave or whatever to make it look impressive.

Best of luck.